# Joomla 3.3.6 with Postgresql

Tags: joomla-3.x, postgresql

I have Joomla 3.3.6 up and running. The backend database I am using currently is MySQL.Now I want to change my database to Postgresql but I don't know where to start. I have Postgresql 9.3.5 installed. I do understand that Postgresql support with Joomla currently has many bugs. However , can anyone guide me ?

Thank You.

Comment: This may help: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/joomlabugsquad/LWQ0zyZ9PMg ... However, unless you are doing this for testing purposes, I would suggest against it

Comment: Due to the lack for community support for Joomla with a Postgresql database you mean ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/690/168