# Does Joomla 3.3.6 support Postgres 10.x?

Tags: joomla-3.x, postgresql

We have Joomla 3.3.6 , I am aware of the following link
https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements

We are planning to  Upgrade DB version to 9.6 which is also at EOL by Nov 2021 because Joomla support matrix only states 9.1+ for Postgres operability. We are uncertain at the moment if Joomla will work with a 10.x or above Postgres release.

This question is related to [Joomla 3.3.6 with Postgresql](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/10435/12352) on JSE.

Comment: Welcome Faisal, please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.

Answer (score 1):

I would read the document you have linked to as 10.x being supported as 9.1+ means anything above 9.1 is okay. A look through the code of PostgreSQL doesn't show up any mention of limitation specific to a version and it appears to gracefully give you a 'is not supported' message if it is not able to handle a particular statement.

I would expect that you would have some sort of test environment set up with a copy of your site and PostgreSQL 10.x  installed to confirm it for yourself beforehand.

Further down the page in your link Joomla 4 has PostgreSQL 11.0 as the minimum level so again I would expect Joomla 3.x to support 9.1 and all of the 10.x levels.